# Pandas create a color for each two value pair

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with XY values which I would like to plot in a scatter plot. I would like to create groups which have a same XY values and apply the same color in the plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1.1, 1.1, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5,10.1],
                   'Y': [3.7, 3.7, 5.6, 5.6, 5.6, 3.2],
                   'ID': ['ID1', 'ID2','ID3','ID4','ID5', 'ID6'})


X        Y         ID         color (hex or RGB)
1.1      3.7       ID1        0,255,255
1.1      3.7       ID2        0,255,255
5.5      5.6       ID3        255,0,255
5.5      5.6       ID4        255,0,255
5.5      5.6       ID5        255,0,255
10.1     3.2       ID6        0,0,255
```

How to map a color for each XY group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a list of colors. After groupby the `X` and `Y` column, get group id with `ngroup()` then map it to the list of colors

```py
colors = ['0,255,255', '255,0,255', '0,0,255']

df['color'] = df.groupby(['X', 'Y']).ngroup().map(dict(enumerate(colors)))
```

```
print(df)

      X    Y   ID      color
0   1.1  3.7  ID1  0,255,255
1   1.1  3.7  ID2  0,255,255
2   5.5  5.6  ID3  255,0,255
3   5.5  5.6  ID4  255,0,255
4   5.5  5.6  ID5  255,0,255
5  10.1  3.2  ID6    0,0,255
```

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Ynjxsjmh's answer, once the column is created you can plot them using `seaborn`'s `hue` parameter:

```
sct = sns.scatterplot(x=df['X'],y=df['Y'],hue=df['color'],c=np.array([[int(w) for w in y] for y in [x.split(",") for x in colors]])/255)
plt.legend(title="My Groups",labels=['Group 1','Group 2','Group 3'])
plt.title("My Scatterplot") 
plt.show(sct)
```

Outputs:

[image]